# How to define an Edit_Text to use it in all the java code

Tags: java, android

Guys I would like to define an `Edit_Text` in the `Main_Activity` class to use it in all the java code like in any method I used the types `public final`,`public`,`private`, `final` but it doesn't work.
 what is the type that I should do?

Comment: Check this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_edittext_control.htm

Comment: create one common edittext and use to all activity is it correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
 public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    // Declare it here
    EditText edt;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Reference it here
        edt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt);

    }

    private void someName() {
        // You can use it here
        edt.setText("Hello");
    }

    private void otherName() {
        // You can also use it here and eveywhere in the whole class
        edt.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers

Comment: @borchvm Oftentimes, a picture is worth more than a thousand words. I think you looked over the comments in the code snippets, which rules out the word "code-only". In this very specific case, the OP is confused where to declare his EditText View. IMO, current code block is a thousand more effective than me explaining writing long sentences like "Put your EditText View variable declaration at the start of your class ... blah blah ...". Thanks for taking the time to point out though.

Answer (score 0):

example.class:

```
EditText et;

public void onCreate(..){
.....
et = findViewbyId(R.id.editText);
// To get the value of et
String str = et.getText().toString().trim();
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See also Explaining entirely code-based answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers